# Python - Pandas, aggregate variant length list into a tidy dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I have the following data frame, each row is a string concatination of event names:

```
0                                              event_1
1                                          other_event
2    other_event, other_event, other_event, other_e...
3    event_3, other_event, other_event, other_event...
4                              some_event, other_event
5    event_1, event_5, some_event, some_event, some...
6                        event_5, event_6, other_event
7                                              event_1
```

I would like to split each row, aggregate by the event name and create a tidy data set that will look like so:

```
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|id |event_1 |other_event |event_3 |some_event |event_5 |event_6 |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|0  |1       |0           |0       |0          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|1  |0       |1           |0       |0          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|2  |0       |4           |0       |0          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|3  |0       |3           |1       |0          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|4  |0       |1           |0       |1          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|5  |1       |0           |0       |3          |1       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|6  |0       |1           |0       |0          |1       |1       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|7  |1       |0           |0       |0          |0       |0       |
+---+--------+------------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I've used `df["events_array"].str.split(",")` but got stuck there, any help would be appereiciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use `Counter` in list comprehension for dictionary of lists and pass to `DataFrame` constructor, replace missing values and convert to integers:

```
from collections import Counter

df = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x.split(", ")) for x in df["events_array"]]).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   event_1  other_event  event_3  some_event  event_5  event_6
0        1            0        0           0        0        0
1        0            1        0           0        0        0
2        0            4        0           0        0        0
3        0            3        1           0        0        0
4        0            1        0           1        0        0
5        1            0        0           3        1        0
6        0            1        0           0        1        1
7        1            0        0           0        0        0
```

Or is possible create DataFrame by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and `expand=True` and then counts by `value_counts` per rows in `apply`:

```
df = (df["events_array"].str.split(', ', expand=True)
                        .apply(pd.value_counts, 1)
                        .fillna(0)
                        .astype(int)
                        )
print (df)
   event_1  event_3  event_5  event_6  other_event  some_event
0        1        0        0        0            0           0
1        0        0        0        0            1           0
2        0        0        0        0            4           0
3        0        1        0        0            3           0
4        0        0        0        0            1           1
5        1        0        1        0            0           3
6        0        0        1        1            1           0
7        1        0        0        0            0           0
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: can you please have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61504377/python-pandas-split-frame-rows-based-on-costume-logic ?