# python pandas - Split frame rows based on costume logic

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DataFrame:

```
   day user  score  total
0    1    A     10     10
1    1    A      5     15
2    2    B      5     20
3    3    C     10     30
4    3    B      5     35
5    3    B      5     40
6    4    C      0     40
7    4    C      5     45
```

the total column was created by using `cumsum` method

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'day'  : [1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4],
    'user' : ['A','A','B','C','B','B','C','C'],
    'score': [10,5,5,10,5,5,0,5]
                   })
df["total"] = df.cumsum()["score"]
print(df.head(10))
```

Now I would like to split the DataFrame, 2 following days as a set (the day's data are of a different length) to get the following groups:

```
   day user  score  total
0    1    A     10     10
1    1    A      5     15  <--- days 1 & 2
2    2    B      5     20
-------------------------
3    3    C     10     30
4    3    B      5     35
5    3    B      5     40 <--- days 3 & 4
6    4    C      0     40
7    4    C      5     45
```

The actual DataFrame is much larger and I may want to group 4 days in a row.
How can I achieve that with pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `factorize` the get the number of div of 2

```
d={x : y for x , y in df.groupby(df.day.factorize()[0]//2)}
... 
... 
{0:    day user  score  total
0    1    A     10     10
1    1    A      5     15
2    2    B      5     20, 1:    day user  score  total
3    3    C     10     30
4    3    B      5     35
5    3    B      5     40
6    4    C      0     40
7    4    C      5     45}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you want ... convert the day column to a timedelta and group on it

```
df.day = pd.to_timedelta(df.day, 'D')

#u could change it to 4 days or whatever number 
grouping = df.resample(rule='2D', on='day')

[v for k,v in grouping]

[     day user  score  total
 0 1 days    A     10     10
 1 1 days    A      5     15
 2 2 days    B      5     20,      day user  score  total
 3 3 days    C     10     30
 4 3 days    B      5     35
 5 3 days    B      5     40
 6 4 days    C      0     40
 7 4 days    C      5     45, Empty DataFrame
 Columns: [day, user, score, total]
 Index: []]

[v for k,v in grouping][0]
day user    score   total
0   1 days  A   10  10
1   1 days  A   5   15
2   2 days  B   5   20

[v for k,v in grouping][1]
day user    score   total
3   3 days  C   10  30
4   3 days  B   5   35
5   3 days  B   5   40
6   4 days  C   0   40
7   4 days  C   5   45
```